# The weak$^\star$ topology is compatible with the vector space structure

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification, topological-vector-spaces, weak-topology

After proving that the weak topology is compatible with the vector space structure, I try to do the same for weak$^\star$ topology, i.e.,

> Let $E$ be a topological vector space and $E^\star$ its topological dual. Let $\sigma(E^\star, E)$ be the weak$^\star$ topology on $E^\star$. We denote by $E^\star_{w^\star}$ the vector space $E^\star$ together with $\sigma(E^\star, E)$. Then $E^\star_{w^\star}$ is a topological vector space.

I posted my proof as an answer below. Could you have a check on my attempt?

Comment: Hello Akyra! You can make a new account but your style is still the same :)

Comment: Anyway, by definition the weak$^*$-topology on $(X, \tau)^*$ is by definition the smallest topology on $(X, \tau)^*$ that makes all evaluation maps $(X, \tau)^* \to \mathbb{K}: f \mapsto f(x)$ (where $x$ ranges over $X$) continuous. You can prove generally that any topology generated by a family of linear functionals (as is the case here) automatically induces a locally convex topological vector structure, so if you go up a bit the generality ladder you get your desired result for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the canonical injection $J:E \to E^{\star\star}, x \mapsto (f \mapsto \langle f, x \rangle)$. Then $\sigma(E^\star, E)$ is the initial topology on $E^\star$ w.r.t. the collection $(Jx)_{x\in E}$ of maps. We consider the linear maps $$\begin{aligned}
T&:E^\star_{w^\star} \times E^\star_{w^\star} &&\to E^\star_{w^\star}, (f, h) &&\mapsto f+h \\
L&: \mathbb R \times E^\star_{w^\star} &&\to E^\star_{w^\star}, (t, f) &&\mapsto tf
\end{aligned}.$$

We want to prove that $T,L$ are continuous. It suffices to show that $$\begin{aligned}
&Jx \circ T:E^\star_{w^\star} \times E^\star_{w^\star} &&\to \mathbb R, (f, h) &&\mapsto \langle Jx, f \rangle + \langle Jx, h \rangle \\
&Jx \circ L: \mathbb R \times E^\star_{w^\star} &&\to \mathbb R, (t, f) &&\mapsto t\langle Jx, f \rangle
\end{aligned}$$ are continuous for all $x \in E$. The claim then follows from below diagrams
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\substack{E^\star_{w^\star} \times E^\star_{w^\star} \\ (f, h)}   &&\substack{ \longrightarrow \\ \longmapsto } \, \substack{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \\ ( \langle Jx, f \rangle, \langle Jx, h \rangle)} && \substack{ \longrightarrow \\ \longmapsto } \, \substack{ \mathbb R \\ \langle Jx, f \rangle + \langle Jx, h \rangle} \\
&\substack{\mathbb R \times E^\star_{w^\star} \\ (t, f)}   &&\substack{ \longrightarrow \\ \longmapsto } \, \substack{\mathbb R \times \mathbb R \\ (t, \langle Jx, f \rangle)} && \substack{ \longrightarrow \\ \longmapsto } \, \substack{ \mathbb R \\ t\langle Jx, f \rangle}
\end{aligned}
$$
and the fact that $Jx$ is also continuous in the weak$^\star$ topology.